# AccessDeniedException when copy file with NIO in linux

Tags: java, linux, copy, nio, access-denied

There is a strange behavior when I use the `Files.copy(Path input, Path output)` method from Java NIO. I use the two Parameters, `REPLACE_EXISTING_FILE` and `COPY_ATTRIBUTES`.

If I copy a file to another destination in windows, it works, like it should. But if I copy it from a linux-directory to another directory, it results in a AccessDeniedException. The file is written, but there is no data in the copied file(0 bytes).

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Path/To/Target/Nas/File
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copyFile(UnixCopyFile.java:243)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:575)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:253)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1225)
    at ch.zkb.asy.asyarch.io.IO.copyFile(IO.java:356)
    at ch.zkb.asy.asyarch.io.IO.copyFile(IO.java:376)
```

Why does it work in Windows, but not in Linux? The permissions should be okay too.

Comment: I would double check the permissions

Comment: But the file is written, but is empty. So in my opinion, if there is a problem with the permissions, the file shouldn't even exist in the target-folder.

Comment: Perhaps the quota is exceeded?

Comment: @jarnbjo What do you mean by exceeded?

Comment: Is your question what the word "exceed" means? Merriam Webster says: to go beyond the limit of (something)

Comment: I am also experiencing this behaviour.  I have read access to all source directories, read access to all subdirectories at the destination, and full write access at the destination.